# How to iterate through table in TTS Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

So, I have a table something along these lines:

```
PlaneToolTip= {['Vickers_0']={title="Vickers F.B.5 Gunbus", text="Vickers F.B.5 Gunbus Variant", row="Vickers", image="planes_creation"},
               ['Vickers_1']={title="Vickers F.B.5 Gunbus", text="Vickers F.B.5 Gunbus Variant 1", typeguid="7a5d62", image="Vickers F.B.5 Gunbus Variant 1"},
               ['Morane_0']={title="Morane Saulnier Type N", text="Morane Saulnier Type N Variant", row="Morane", image="planes_creation"},
               ['Morane_1']={title="Morane Saulnier Type N", text="Morane Saulnier Type N Variant 1", typeguid="dbf582", image="Morane Saulnier Type N Variant 1"},
               ['Morane_2']={title="Morane Saulnier Type N", text="Morane Saulnier Type N Variant 2", typeguid="73c10f", image="Morane Saulnier Type N Variant 2"}}
```

Hello, I use Lua(Tabletopsimulator), and would like to search for something in the table, such as like "title".

```
for a, b in pairs (PlaneToolTip) do
         for b, c in pairs (PlaneToolTip [a]) do
             if c == "Morane Saulnier Type N" then
             ...
           end
        end

end
```

Then it should output all suitable "typeguid". Like as "dbf582", "73c10f".

Thanks for the help
Radoan

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_typeguids(variant)
      local typeguids = {}
      for _,entry in pairs(PlaneToolTip) do
        if entry.typeguid and entry.text:find(variant)  then
          table.insert(typeguids, entry.typeguid)
        end
      end

      return typeguids
    end

print(table.concat(get_typeguids("Morane Saulnier Type N"), ", "))
```